# Псково-ПечЕрский и Киево-ПечЕрская? Не через Ё?

Tags: орфография, топонимика, е-или-ё

Прошу прощения, если не по теме задаю вопрос, просто не знаю, где ещё спросить.

Слышал от некоторых людей (нечасто, но бывает), даже от одного иеромонаха, как они произносят: Псково-Печ**ё**рский и Киево-Печ**ё**рская — через Ё.
Хочу, чтобы мне подтвердили, что это неправильно, а не наоборот.

Comment: А я так старалась во время правки вопроса сохранить Ваши задумки и Вашу индивидуальность... Не вышло.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Ничего.) Спасибо, что старались!) Я постарался оставить его в Вашем вкусе также. Удалось? (Вы хотели заголовок говорящим сделать ведь? Это правильно, согласен с Вами.)

Comment: Забыл отметить, что у Вас почти и получилось сделать в моём стиле! ;)

Comment: Просто сегодня я немного "пошурудила" _недопустимые метки_ (текущих-то вопросов практически не было — момент удобный). Я рада, что мы находим общий язык, потому что, к сожалению, с другими участниками это не всегда удается. Год с небольшим назад Вы вовсю правили мои сообщения (а я так переживала, что не соответствую!).

Comment: И я тоже рад!!)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос. 
Псково-Печерский и Киево-Печерская. Произношение с Ё неправильно. Такие вещи проверяются не общими рассуждениями, а консультацией у топонимистов.

Название образовано от древнерусского, оно же церковнословянское, - **печера** (пещера), Менять его нет нужды. Многочисленные топонимы типа "Печора" того же происхождения, но там закреплена более современная фонетика.

Произношение Ё в "Печера, печерский" ошибочно ещё и потому, что для передачи такого произношения использовалось бы орфографическое О. Довод не абсолютный, но как дополнительный вполне годится.

Что же касается обсуждений перехода Е->Ё вообще, тем более в плане взаимоотношения русского и церковнославянского языков, то это дебри непролазные.

Достаточно здесь сказать, что топонимы (а данные названия вполне относятся к топонимам) обычно сохраняют исторические названия гораздо дольше, чем имена (включая несобственные), их породившие.

Comment: *Есть сомнение, что названия монастырей как-то согласовывались святыми отцами у топонимистов* - это к Задорнову.

Comment: К Задорнову. У него и поинтересуетесь насчет курицы и яйца.

Comment: Нет, не часто. Ровно тогда, когда его адепты голоса подают.  Ну до какого состояния мозгов надо дойти, чтобы обвинить ученых в том, что их "не слушается" наука, которую  они изучают? Задорнов головного мозга.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32117/discussion-between-behemothus-and-shampar).

Comment: *Насчёт «Ответа на вопрос»*  -  *названия монастырей как-то согласовывались святыми отцами у топонимистов* - ))))

Comment: Обрывки захватите.

Comment: А я не об этом. Мне нет нужды договариваться с Вами. Если Вы пошутили, то шутка неудачная. А если всерьез, то я Вам уже сказал, куда идти.

Comment: Скатертью дорога! Не шучу!

Answer (score 1):

При написании *Е* (ударной) надо иметь в виду, что названия свои все печерские монастыри (в Нижнем Новгороде, Киеве, Псковской губернии) получили от ***печера*** — совр. ***пещера***, а не от др.-русс. ***печора*** — финское племя или река (Печора) на севере от Перми. Их история начиналась однотипными поселениями монашествующих отшельников в уединённых и общежитийных пещерах, что было характерным явлением раннего христианства.

В любом случае это не **Ё**, т. к. такой буквы в церковно-славянском языке нет. Она в составе только гражданского алфавита. Путаницу е/ё вносят, к примеру, самоназвания жилых районов на месте Печёрской (?) слободы в НН с «историческими» названиями типа Верхних Печёр, Верхнепечёрская улица.

Это топонимическое художество относится к последней четверти XX в.

Comment: Да, но когда называешь монастырь или Лавру, говоришь при этом **по-русски**!

Comment: При чем тут по-русски? А через е   не по-русски?

Comment: Я понимал, что изначально это от пещер, просто теоретически это связь могла и исказиться.

Comment: Конечно, через Е по-русски, но в русском есть и Ё тоже, то есть вариант сказать через Ё не исключён рамками самого языка.

Comment: Мы говорим по-русски о русском, русское — не может проникать в церковно-славянское. Только наоборот.

Comment: Я так и думал, просто хотел подтверждения, так что спасибо!

Comment: Артем, Ё появилось намного позже. Официальное название не изменилось. Многие просто путают. В Советском энциклопедическом словаре, М. 1989г, это название дано через е, а не ***Ё***,

Comment: Ну да, я слышал, что Ё появилась в конце XVIII века. Просто не мог полностью исключить вариант, что бывшее Е могло преобразоваться в Ё в соответствии с современным языком.

Comment: *Ну да, я слышал, что Ё появилась в конце XVIII века. * - буква но не звук, её обозначаемый в подобных сочетаниях (ударный О после мягкого согласного на месте исторического Е). Это фонетическое явление гораздо старше, иногда там писали **IO** или **ЬО** - как в украинском.

Answer (score 0):

Название «Печоры» происходит от старо-рус. «печеры» (пещеры), дату открытия которых монастырская летопись определяет 1392 годом. Первое упоминание населённого пункта Печор (точнее — пещерной церкви) относится к 1473 году, когда была освящена Успенская церковь, первоначально прорубленная в ***пещере,*** и, таким образом, основан православный Псково-Печерский Свято-Успенский монастырь.